# What does this mean - "Intel HD Graphics (WWAN or mSATA capable)"?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, wwan

On the Lenovo online shop when customising a new laptop under **"System Graphics"** it offers an option of:

```
Intel HD Graphics (WWAN or mSATA capable)
```

1. I thought WWAN provides Internet access via a simcard, and mSATA connects a harddrive.  What do these have to do with the System Graphics?
2. Is **`capable`** marketing-speak for "does not actually include either feature" or normal-speak for "provides both these things"?

x-------

- Digging through the manual for the current E330 (AU) it shows an expansion slot for either a WWAN module *OR* an mSATA. Clearly, on this model at least, you'll need the relevant module there to get either feature. Still, doesn't explain why the graphics is dependent.
- When trying to customise the same model your screen choice dictates the addition of the WWAN module...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am guessing, it's about either sharing resources if the hard drive is fast enough (like virtual RAM). Great question! According to the sites, capable means the antennae are in place, but you may still need to buy parts!

Comment: Could the WWAN be dependant on the graphics because the slot to put the sim card is mounted on the screen?

Comment: You might be confusing eSATA with mSATA (although that doesn't make any more sense either).

Comment: Maybe the wwan only works when there is a big antenna - one that is built into the display?!

Comment: Technical features of PCs are often subject to errors by those who are responsible for marketing them or creating descriptions of them.  You should search for the user's manual, or ideally the service manual, to precisely know what this means.

Answer (score 1):

My research has shown there are 2 reasons any device would use this technology. I am going to explain both but ultimately I don't know which is relevant to you (sorry). It is not about connecting to the internet, it is how the device connects to your PC or how the device connects to a monitor which is too far for a cable.

This is easier to visualise if you think that your graphics cards is external.

Long term I think this will be more popular (having external cards) as they will have their own dedicated psu, ram, cpu etc and things like thunderbolt will make this happen but this is off the point.  :)

So if you have a graphic card which could be placed internal or external you can now choose how to connect it to your pc... Wired or wireless. Well, this would make sense if it was WLAN but it is WWAN so my guess is it is an attempt to make the unit as stand alone as possible. Maybe the card has a unique IP and even a web page for remote management or independent updating? Maybe it is used for sending out reports, I really don't know.

Now I think this bit is more relevant to you. To focus more on the connectivity you can also use this to send video wirelessly. So your PC could send your video to another device in another room of a house, like your TV. I would imagine it is useful in conferences where you want to do a presentation but instead of having to get all the cables plugged in, which trails the desk and floor, you just connect like it was a wireless router.

http://news.techworld.com/mobile-wireless/10900/vendors-to-show-first-wireless-graphics-card/

http://m.pcgamer.com/2011/01/13/nvidia-release-announce-wireless-graphics-card

Answer (score 0):

It might be that choosing that graphics option makes them build the laptop with a different motherboard which includes the slot that would fit a WWAN card or mSATA card (this might be a tiny PCIe slot).